# Javascript ellipses (...) and colons (:)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, syntax, operators

I have a couple of JS syntax questions.

1. First, what's a good resource to get up to speed with JS syntax similar to those below?
2. In the code, are Q1 and Q2 labels? Also, what is the ... for?

   ```
   const Q1: Query = {
     'isChild': {
       $ne: true,
     },
   };

   const Q2: Query = {
     ...Q1,
     'isL': true,
     'stat': {
       $in: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
     },
   };
   ```
3. Below, is `: Promise<Event>` similar to a then statement?

   ```
   async update(event: Event): Promise<Event> {
       debug(`Updating event`, event);
       const { id, ...fields } = event;
       invariant(!!id, 'id is required');
       const fieldsWithTimestamps = withTimestamps<EventFields>(fields);
       debug(`Update ${id}`, fieldsWithTimestamps);
       await collection.updateOne({ _id: id }, fieldsWithTimestamps);
       return { id, ...fieldsWithTimestamps };
   }
   ```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is not JS, it's TS (typescript)

Comment: Hi @Amit yes I was about to delete this when I realized it's typescript. I haven't used TS so ...

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I'm relabeling but would also look at TS

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators

Answer (score 4):

For learning the syntax of a language quickly, I'm a fan of [LearnXinYminutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/). Here's [their page for javascript](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/javascript/).

Moreover, your snippets are written in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) which is a superset of JavaScript that adds type annotations. Thats what the `: Promise<Event>` syntax is. It is a type annotation indicating the return type of the `update` function as a `Promise<event>`.

Finally, Q1 and Q2 are objects, and the `...` syntax is called a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

All this is relatively well known javascript (barring the typescript annotations), and you should familiarize yourself with the language elsewhere rather than asking here. StackOverflow works better the more specific your question is.